# Move Constructor and = operator for Shared Pointer

Tags: c++, move, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

Say, I have a class:

```
class GameObject ///header file
{
    ....
    std::shared_ptr<Transform> transform;
}
///cpp file
//Copy Ctor
GameObject::GameObject(const GameObject& rhs)
   :transform(rhs.transform)
{}
//Move CTor
GameObject::GameObject(GameObject&& rhs)
    :transform(std::move(rhs.transform))
{}
```

1. Is this the correct to create a move constructor for a class that has a shared_ptr member variable? Or do I need to to call `rhs.transform.reset()` to de-allocate the rhs after the move?
2. How about the copy constructor?
3. Presumably, the copy and move assignments look basically the same as the ctors, just with a `return *this` at the end?

Comment: The copy constructor you have here is only a shallow copy, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: @dwcanillas There's no shallow copy occurring.

Comment: @0x499602D2  aren't we looking at constructor 9 here? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr

Comment: @dwcanillas Yes, my mistake. There is a shallow copy.

Comment: I doubt that having two copies of an object share a transform is what you really want. It doesn't make much sense to have an object's transform as a `shared_ptr` in the first place, as it presumably is an internal detail of the object and *not* shared. Even having it dynamically allocated seems a bit odd, unless you misuse null pointers to indicate "transformlessness".

Comment: @dwcanillas But if that's not what he wants he probably shouldn't be using a *shared*_ptr.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your copy and move constructors are equivalent to the implicit ones. Remove them. You don't need to write them out explicitly as the copy and move constructor of the `std::shared_ptr` correctly implement both operations.

> Or do I need to to call `rhs.transform.reset()` to de-allocate the `rhs` after the move?

No, the moved-from object will lose ownership after the move:

> ```
> shared_ptr(shared_ptr&& r) noexcept;
> template<class Y> shared_ptr(shared_ptr<Y>&& r) noexcept;
> ```
>
> Remark: The second constructor shall not participate in overload resolution unless `Y*` is convertible to `T*`.
>
> Effects: Move-constructs a shared_ptr instance from r.
>   Postconditions: `*this` shall contain the old value of `r`. **`r` shall be empty. `r.get() == nullptr`.**

As for the copy and move-assignment operators, they too will be equivalent. Move-assignment will correctly transfer ownership and the copy-constructor will perform a shallow copy so that both `shared_ptr`s have ownership.

If a shallow copy (shared ownership) is really want you want, then `shared_ptr` is the correct tool. Otherwise I'd suggest using `unique_ptr` if you want to implement *unique ownership*.

Answer (score 1):

1. This code is correct. If `GameObject` is movable, it makes perfect sense to move `transform`. The `shared_ptr` move constructor will do the right thing for you here - it will *transfer ownership* of the `Transform`. You do not need to call `reset()`, that is an extraneous operation - you should only need to rely on your member object's move constructors to be properly implemented, which for `shared_ptr` they most certainly are.
2. Member-wise copy is correct, and `shared_ptr` will copy correctly for you.
3. Yes.

Note that if your class entirely consists of objects that have all the right operators implemented, you do not need to write them yourself. The default constructors and assignment operators will already do member-wise copy/move, which is exactly correct. Not having to write any of the basic 5 functions is called the [Rule of Zero](https://web.archive.org/web/20151006051620/http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/rule-of-zero/):

```
class GameObject {
    std::shared_ptr<Transform> transform;
    std::shared_ptr<SomethingElse> foo;
};

GameObject obj = ...;
GameObject obj2 = obj;             // correct by default
GameObject obj3 = std::move(obj2); // correct by default
```

Answer (score 0):

1. By the standard, the move constructor for `shared_ptr` leaves the original `shared_ptr` empty, so no `reset()` call is needed.
2. The copy constructor you have written will share one `Transform` object between several `GameObject`s. Maybe this is what you want. If not, you need something like `transform(new Transform(*rhs.transform))`.
3. Essentially, but you'd use assignment instead of constructing the members (since the latter wouldn't be syntactically valid). Be wary of code duplication, though. An alternative approach could be to use an idiom like copy-and-swap to delegate the work back to the constructors:

   ```
   GameObject &operator=(const GameObject &rhs) {
     GameObject tmp(rhs);
     tmp.swap(*this);
     return *this;
   }
   ```

Also, as has been already noted by several other people, if your constructors and assignments are identical to the compiler-generated defaults (as they currently are), it's shorter and safer to remove them and just use the defaults instead.